# SCCM - No Reports Available In The Reporting Section

Tags: sccm, ssrs

I am trying to set up the Reporting feature in the SCCM Console (Version 1910) but I can't get anything to appear under the Reports tab - the text 'No Items Found' is displayed instead. I was able to troubleshoot and eradicate a variety of issues that appeared to be relevant to this problem but the issues outlined below still remain:

- In the Site Status tab, the status of the Reporting Services Point is listed as Critical.
- In the Component Status tab, everything is fine except for SMS_REST_PROVIDER, where Warning is the Status listed.
- The only error message that I can see in the 'Messages' section relates to the SMS_REST_PROVIDER Component: Message-ID: 11610; Error Message: Connection to administration service is unsuccessful.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised what the problem is - I'm trying to run SSRS on a server that is a Domain Controller (small lab testing environment; non-production). I tried re-installing SSRS and it refused to install due to the DC role being installed. I installed SSRS previously - prior to installing the DC role.